# I want to run my else statement in (views.py) but when server is run it automatically go to the if statement?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

#views.py
class AddQuestion(View):

```
def post(self, request):
    forms = QuestionForm(request.POST)
    if forms.is_valid:
        forms.save()
        print("If statement")
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        print("else statement")
        return render(request,'file/addQuestion.html')
   

def get(self, request):
    forms = QuestionForm()
    context = {'forms': forms}
    return render(request,'file/addQuestion.html',context)
```

#forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Question
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = "__all__"

    

def clean_answer(self):
    answer = self.cleaned_data['answer']
    option1 = self.cleaned_data['option1']
    option2 = self.cleaned_data['option2']
    option3 = self.cleaned_data['option3']
    option4 = self.cleaned_data['option4']
    if answer == option1 or answer == option2 or answer == option3 or answer == option4:
        return answer
    else: 
        raise ValidationError("Select an answer from the options.")
```

Comment: sorry when i want to add a Question

Comment: `is_valid` is a method, you need to call it - `if forms.is_valid():`

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: thank you now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `forms.is_valid():` instead of `forms.is_valid:`

```
def post(self, request):
    forms = QuestionForm(request.POST)
    if forms.is_valid():
        forms.save()
        print("If statement")
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        print("else statement")
        return render(request,'file/addQuestion.html')
```